# How can I cut a certain part of bash output out?

Tags: bash, google-cloud-storage

I am new to bash, and I have a Minecraft server running right on Google Cloud right now. I am making a backup and restore bash script, and I have it working with backups on the disk. I want to put the backups on Google Cloud Storage to make it easier to manage.

My problem however is when I want to list the backups to the end user using the command `gsutil ls gs://test-1234/`, it shows: `gs://test-1234/foo1.mcworld, gs://test-1234/foo2.mcworld` and so on. Is there a way that I can just show the backup name without the `gs://test-1234` before it?

Comment: You could pipe your command, for instance, to a `sed` filter: `... | sed 's!^gs://test-1234!!'`.

Comment: Or simply pipe to `sed 's/^.*\///'` (if it is one filename per-line)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully a slight improvement to @RenaudPacalet's suggestion, insofar as it should generically remove *any* prefix after the `gs://` part.

```
gsutil ls gs://ANYTHING | sed 's|^gs://[^//]*||'
```

Answer (score 0):

when using gsutil ls .... at the end add `| awk -F "/"  '{print $(NF-0)}'`

so..

```
gsutil ls gs://test-1234/ | awk -F "/"  '{print $(NF-0)}'
```

Comment: Why do you think you need `$(NF-0)` instead of simply `$NF`?

Comment: yeh, you are right, we dont have anything past file name.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your provided sample data it appears to be two paths on a single line, e.g.

```
gs://test-1234/foo1.mcworld, gs://test-1234/foo2.mcworld
```

(separated by `", "` - a comma and a space)

If that is the case and it is not one pathname per-line, then you will need to separate the pathnames first and then split on `"/"` which can be done with `awk` as:

```
awk -F", " '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {n = split ($i, arr, "/"); print arr[n]}}'
```

Just pipe your output to it, e.g.

```
$ gsutil ls gs://test-1234/ |
awk -F", " '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {n = split ($i, arr, "/"); print arr[n]}}'
```

**Example Use/Output**

Using your sample data from the question:

```
$ echo "gs://test-1234/foo1.mcworld, gs://test-1234/foo2.mcworld" | 
awk -F", " '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {n = split ($i, arr, "/"); print arr[n]}}'
foo1.mcworld
foo2.mcworld
```

---

If you have one pathname per-line, then it is as simple as piping to `sed` with:

```bash
sed 's/^.*\///'
```

Which just outputs everything following the last `'/'` in each line.